# Android Studio find and replace in code

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new in Android coding. Is there any way to replace the search result (Ctrl+F) with another text in code?
After pressing Ctrl+f it just opens search menu, unlike Eclipse.

Comment: find and replace `Ctrl+R`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just use **Find and Replace** **CTRL+R**

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Ctrl+Shift+R for Replace all in Android Studio in windows

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Ctrl+F

1. After pressing it you will have a view where you will select "Select All Occurrences" button [image: Ctrl+F menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1xmb.png)
2. By just typing the new text you will replace it
   [image: Replacing all matches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjZUQ.png)